# Can anyone provide a link to an online partition calculator?

Tags: integer-partitions, math-software

I am trying to learn about partitions and I would like to experiment a bit with a calculator. That's the only way I know how to teach myself something. I am not really interested in code because I can't code and I know where to find the code. I simply wouldn't have asked the question. Thanks.

Comment: How about [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partitions+of+10)?

Comment: thank you very much. I really appreciate?